# IPython.parallel ValueError: cannot create an OBJECT array from memory buffer

Tags: python, ipython, scikit-learn, ipython-parallel

I'm trying to write a function to be executed in several IPython engines. The function takes a pandas Series as an argument. Each element of the Series is a string, and the whole Series constitutes a corpus for TF.IDF computation.

After reading IPython parallel documentation and some tutorials, it seems to be quite straightforward to do, and I came up with the following:

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.parallel import Client


def calculemus(corpus):
    from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1, stop_words='english')

    return vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)


review = pd.read_csv('review.csv')['text']
review = review.fillna('')

client = Client()

r = client[-1].apply(calculemus, review).get()
```

**BUT** I got this error instead:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)/xxx/site-packages/IPython/zmq/serialize.pyc in unpack_apply_message(bufs, g, copy)
    154                     sa.data = m.bytes
    155 
--> 156     args = uncanSequence(map(unserialize, sargs), g)
    157     kwargs = {}
    158     for k in sorted(skwargs.iterkeys()):
/xxx/site-packages/IPython/utils/newserialized.pyc in unserialize(serialized)
    175 
    176 def unserialize(serialized):
--> 177     return UnSerializeIt(serialized).getObject()
/xxx/site-packages/IPython/utils/newserialized.pyc in getObject(self)
    159                 buf = self.serialized.getData()
    160                 if isinstance(buf, (bytes, buffer, memoryview)):
--> 161                     result = numpy.frombuffer(buf, dtype = self.serialized.metadata['dtype'])
    162                 else:
    163                     raise TypeError("Expected bytes or buffer/memoryview, but got %r"%type(buf))
ValueError: cannot create an OBJECT array from memory buffer
```

I'm not sure what the problem is, could someone enlighten me on this?

## UPDATE

Apparently the error says exactly what it says. If I do this:

```
r = client[-1].apply(calculemus, np.array(review, dtype=str)).get()
```

it kinda works.

So the next question is, is this a feature or a limitation of IPython?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in IPython 0.13 that should be fixed in master.  There is a special case for serializing numpy arrays that avoids copying data, and this behavior is triggered by an `isinstance(numpy.ndarray)` check. This was inappropriate, because `isinstance` catches subclasses, which includes pandas objects, but those pandas objects (and array subclasses in general) should *not* be treated in the same way, as metadata will be lost, and reconstruction on the other side will often fail.

#### PS:

```
r = client[-1].apply(calculemus, np.array(review, dtype=str)).get()
```

is equivalent to

```
r = client[-1].apply_sync(calculemus, np.array(review, dtype=str))
```

Comment: I have come across the same problem and just used `.tolist()` method of the numpy array and it worked just fine.